# JSON and Arrays mixed up (in PHP)

Tags: php, sql, arrays, json, foreach

This is what I get from my SQL selection. The data is correct, now I'd like to echo it by foreach.

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [sql_column] => [{"1":"value1", "2":"value2", "3":"value3"}] ) )
```

What I've tried (and which didn't work) was:

```
$obj = json_decode($arr);
foreach($obj as $data){
echo $data->sql_column->1; //this should echo "value1", but it doesn't
}
```

Does anyone see my mistake? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should not save JSON into mysql, first of all.

Comment: @moonwave why is that? if you spoke of a serialized array, which may contain special or `null` characters when containing special data, you might be right, but a json array? explain yourself!

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier because you use a _relational_ database in order to have normalised data - if you plan to store JSON strings well, you end up with an unnormalised schema [i.e. unsearchable, unquerable]. Different thing is if you need to store a tiny bit of data, that would be acceptable then.

Comment: @moonwave I see. You're right that it's not intended to be a replacement for normal data fields or a table, but for storing session variables between connections for exemple, it's of much use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$arr` is the array you posted then you can't `json_decode` it since it's an array and not a `JSON` string.

```
//First you need to get the string
$json = $arr[0]->sql_column;
//Then decode
$data = json_decode($json);
//Then loop
foreach($data as $key => $value){
   echo "$key = $value \n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your json seems to be complicated (double dimensional array), but you can fetch values from it in this manner:

```
foreach($arr as $data){
    $json = json_decode($data->sql_column);
    $temp = (array)$json[0];
    foreach($temp as $k=>$v){
        print($v."<br/>");
    }
}
```

I hope you get an idea...

I used foreach for $arr to cover multi values, you can omit that if you want:

```
$data=$arr[0];    
$json = json_decode($data->sql_column);
$temp = (array)$json[0];
foreach($temp as $k=>$v){
print($v."<br/>");
}
```